# Displaying a date field from the java DB in 3 combo boxes in a Jform(GUI)

Tags: java, sql, database, date, combobox

So I've been busy making a program that pulls preset data from a java db in netbeans and displays it in a Jform GUI.

All of my data displays correctly except for my date. In my db it is set in a date field so it is one value, but I need it to display in 3 separate combo boxes.

After a long time of testing I figued out that my program is trying to insert the full date being "dd/mm/yy" into the "dd" combo box, the "mm" combo box and the "yy" combo box all at the same time even though these boxes don't have the correct parameters please can you help me figure out how to solve this.

here is my code:

```
  try
   {
        //Connect to the DB
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PAT_DB";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        String QuerySearch = "SELECT * FROM TBLPATIENTS WHERE PATIENT_ID = "+List1.getSelectedValue()+"";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QuerySearch);


        while(rs.next())
        {
            PatientID_field.setText(rs.getString(1));
            FirstName_field.setText(rs.getString(2));
            LastName_field.setText(rs.getString(3));

            //This is where im having problems
            year_field.setSelectedItem(rs.getDate(4));
            month_field.setSelectedItem(rs.getDate(4));
            day_field.setSelectedItem(rs.getDate(4));
            //This is where im having problems

            Sex_field.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(5));
            Address_field.setText(rs.getString(6));
            City_field.setText(rs.getString(7));
            PostalCode_field.setText(rs.getString(8));
            Charge_field.setText(rs.getString(9));
            Paid_field.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(10));
            DoctorID_field.setText(rs.getString(11));

        }
```

P.S. I've tried changing the date fields to .getString and there is no difference.
The numbers in the brackets eg.

```
DoctorID_field.setText(rs.getString(11));
```

That (11) corresponds to the column that the data is situated in the table in the DB. If I label more than 11 the statement goes out of bounds and it doesn't work.

Here is a screenshot of my GUI:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
year_field.setSelectedItem(rs.getDate(4));
month_field.setSelectedItem(rs.getDate(4));
day_field.setSelectedItem(rs.getDate(4));
```

Well if the data in the database is a `Date` then you need to access the `Date` first:

```
Date date = rs.getDate(4);
```

Now most of the methods in the `Date` class are deprecated so you don't really want to use that class. Instead you can use a `Calendar`:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime( date );
```

Now you can access the day, month and year separately from the Calendar:

```
int day = calendar.get( Calendar.DATE );
day_field.setSelectedIndex( day );
```

Note you may need to use (day - 1), I don't remember if the day is zero based or not.

Do the same for the month and year. For the year you will need to convert the year to a String so you can use the `setSelectedItem(...)` method, since you are not going to have 2000 years in your combo box model.